# numbers are rounded after using ','.join(map(str, myList))

Tags: python

Hello Question regarding `myList = ','.join(map(str, myList))`

`myList` contains eg: `0.23905884 0.15364707` etc...

but after using the `','.join(map(str, myList))`

`myList` contains: `0.239059,0.153647` etc...

So you see the numbers are rounded. I like to have after comma separating: `0.23905884,0.15364707` etc...

Anybody knows the answer?

Comment: Can you show an actual example with `myList = ...` defined?

Comment: Can not reproduce on 3.6, it gives me `0.23905884,0.15364707`

Comment: I used following code

import scipy.misc
img_array = scipy.misc.imread("Test_Set/TestSet_03/2828_my_own_4.png", flatten=True)
img_data = 255.0 - img_array.reshape(784)
img_data = (img_data / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.01
img_data = ','.join(map(str, img_data))
 
print (img_data)

First I've got an image (28x28 pixels)
I reshape this in a list of 784 numbers
As said in the list of 784 numbers values appears as 0.23905884 0.15364707

And after using the command: img_data = ','.join(map(str, img_data))
img_date was comma separated but as said rounded :-(

I did it in iPython.

Comment: Please can you put that code into the question? It's more difficult to help if we can't reproduce. What's the type of `myList`? If it's a NumPy ndarray, what's its `dtype` and `shape`? What version of NumPy do you have?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with python rounding the float for the string representation.  Here's some sample code showing the issue:

```
>>> b = 5.78888888888888888888888888888
>>> print("{0:.3f}".format(b))
5.789
>>> print(b)
5.78888888889
>>> print("{0:.18f}".format(b))
5.788888888888888751
>>> print("{0:.24f}".format(b))
5.788888888888888750727801
```

The later issues with accuracy have to do with the accuracy of binary floating points, but you can at least see how to change the length of the display.  For your particular issue, you can try something along these lines:

```
myList = ','.join(map(lambda x: "{0:.8f}".format(x), myList))
```

Comment: Ok tnx M Dillon. I will try your proposal. Once done I let you know something

Comment: If this works for you, you might want to consider changing it to list comprehension instead of a map, which I should have done in my original answer, as I believe it's a bit more pythonic.  The computation is the same, but the syntax would change to: `myList = ','.join(["{0:.8f}".format(x) for x in myList])`

Comment: Glad to hear! I'd appreciate it if you accepted my answer.